# Given three points on a circle, how should they be arranged to give the maximum area triangle?

Tags: geometry, area

I am trying to achieve multiple solutions to this problem using technology (i.e. Geometer's sketchpad) or perhaps alternatively solving without technology.

I am not sure if I am in the right direction in working on:
- 3 unique points create a triangle
- creating a bisection of each side
- thus, a unique circumcentre = unique circum-radius
- which creates a circle

Any guiding ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Fix any two points and draw the chord $AB$. Now the area is maximised if the third point $C$ is farthest from $AB$, i.e. on the perpendicular bisector and when the triangle is isosceles.

As we can choose the first two points arbitrarily, the triangle has to be in fact equilateral.

Comment: After drawing each perpendicular bisector of AB, AC, and BC, is the  triangle's area at its largest when it is equilateral because the length of each bisector is at its maximum height?

Comment: For any two points (base), we have to choose the third point to get maximum height. This happens when the third point is on the bisector. Which implies isosceles. Which implies equilateral.

Answer (score 0):

A fuzzy handwaving argument (which often works) ...

The problem is "symmetric" in the three points. There is nothing special about any one of them; they all have equivalent roles and status.

Therefore the solution must also be symmetric, in the same sense. So, the triangle has to be equilateral.

Comment: This is called intuition, and not a proof.

Comment: Well, I didn't say it was a proof, I said it was a "fuzzy handwaving argument". Do you think that mathematics is only about proofs? Sometimes intuition is just as valuable as proof.

Comment: Yes, I see. I solve it this way in objective exams, always.